# turtle programm Java, handing over variety of classes as a parameter and check which class it is

Tags: java

i am trying to programm a Turtle programm in Java following the Visitor pattern.
therefore i have the Visitor:

```
public interface Visitor {

void visit(Go go);
void visit(Turn turn);
void visit(Call call);
void visit(PenDown pendown);
void visit(PenUp penup);
void visit(Repeat repeat);
void visit(Sequence sequence);
void visit(Subroutine subroutine);
```

}

and the Abstract Visitor which should implement some of the visit methods:

```
public abstract class AbstractVisitor implements Visitor {
protected Turtle turtle;

 protected AbstractVisitor(Turtle turtle){
    this.turtle = turtle;
 }

 public AbstractVisitor() {

 }

 public void visit(Turn turn){
      turtle.turn(turn.w);

 }
 public void visit(Sequence sequence){

 }
 public void visit(Repeat repeat) {
      int d = repeat.rep;

    for(int i = 0; i<repeat.rep; i++){
        for(int s = 0; s<repeat.d.size(); s++){
        }
    }
 }
 public void visit(Subroutine subroutine) {

 }
 public  void visit(Call call) {

 }

 public  void visit(PenDown penDown) {

 }
 public  void visit(PenUp penUp) {

 }
```

}

i am Trying to implement the visit(Repeat repeat)

```
public class Repeat implements Stmt {
public int rep;
public List<Object> d;

public Repeat(int i,Stmt ... s1) {
    this.rep = i;
    for (int q = 0; q < s1.length; q++) {
        d.add( s1[q]);
    }

}

@Override
public void accept(Visitor v) {
    {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}
```

}

this method should get an integer i and some other classes which also implements the Interface Stmt

```
public interface Stmt {
void accept(Visitor v);
```

}

like the Class Go

```
public class Go implements Stmt {
```

public double dist;

```
public Go(double d){
    if(d<0 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Die Strecke muss positiv sein");


    } this.dist = d;
}

public void accept(Visitor v) {

}
```

}

So You should be able to hand over an Integer i and as many Classes like Go.
the repeat class should do the visit method for each class handed over and repeat it i times.

Now my Question is how can I check which Class is in the Array of Stmt's I hand over to Repeat? Or is it Wrong how I did the parameters in Repeat?

As a example i want to be able to call
PROG1.accept(visitor)

with
public static final Stmt PROG1 = new Repeat(4, new Go(50), new Turn(90));

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand completely your problem! But if your question is :

You have an Interface

```
public interface Stmt {
  void accept(Visitor v);
  }
```

and you have two classes implementing this interface each them has a different body for the accept method

```
public class X implements Stmt{

 public void accept(Visitor v) {
   //code
 }

}
```

and

```
public class Y implements Stmt{

 public void accept(Visitor v) {
   //code
 }}
```

and your question as I understand it is:
HOW do I know which body will be used if I call the accept() method ! is the accept() from X class or the accept() from the Y class ??

Answer :
it depends on your main application, as you know you cannot instantiate an interface!
so it depends on which class you have instantiated!
you will have for example :

```
Stmt var = new X();
```

for this one var.accept() will call the body from the X class!

Comment: I understand this, but i have the issue, that my Class Repeat will be created like this        new Repeat(4, new Go(50), new Turn(90)) and I need to check whether there is a new Go() or a new Turn() so I can call the right method in the AbstractVisitor

Comment: in this case, you will have two objects created first: **new Go()** object will be created and **new Turn()** object, then using those two objects the **new Repeat(...)** will be created!
after that, you called accept(visitor) (assuming that you instance the abstractVisitor Object!)
so the compiler will use this method visit(Repeat repeat) because you did v.visit(this) and "this" refer to a Repeat object !

Comment: Yes, i want to use the visit(Repeat repeat) but in this function I need to get the parameters of  new Repeat(4, new Go(50), new Turn(90)) to call the visit(Go go) and the visit(Turn turn)

Comment: Aaah, now I understand what you mean, you want to get the created objects (new Go()) and (new Turn()), for that: just call : (lets say **Repeat obj = new Repeat(4, new Go(50), new Turn(90)**)
so you can retrieve the **Go** Object created from (Go)obj.d[0] and (Turn)obj.d[1]

Comment: don't forget to add a cast (Go) & (Turn) to force the compiler to understand it as a Go & Turn Object!

Comment: But i don't know which parameters I get, so how can I extract the Objects from the parameters?